# Prevent reading data multiple times using Dask

Tags: python, pandas, parallel-processing, dask

What can i do to prevent same file being read more then twice?

For the background, i have below detail

Im trying to read list of file in a folder, transform it, output it into a file, and check the gap before and after transformation

first for the reading part

```
def load_file(file):
   df = pd.read_excel(file)
   return df

file_list = glob2.glob("folder path here")
future_list = [delayed(load_file)(file) for file in file_list]
read_result_dd = dd.from_delayed(future_list)
```

After that , i will do some transformation to the data:

```
def transform(df):
   # do something to df
   return df

transformation_result = read_result_dd.map_partitions(lambda df: transform(df))
```

i would like to achieve 2 things:
first to get the transformation output:

```
Outputfile = transformation_result.compute()
Outputfile.to_csv("path and param here")
```

second to get the comparation

```
read_result_comp = read_result_dd.groupby("groupby param here")["result param here"].sum().reset_index()
transformation_result_comp = transformation_result_dd.groupby("groupby param here")["result param here"].sum().reset_index()

Checker = read_result_dd.merge(transformation_result, on=['header_list'], how='outer').compute()
Checker.to_csv("path and param here")
```

The problem is if i call `Outputfile` and `Checker` in sequence, i.e.:

```
Outputfile = transformation_result.compute()
Checker = read_result_dd.merge(transformation_result, on=['header_list'], how='outer').compute()

Outputfile.to_csv("path and param here")
Checker.to_csv("path and param here")
```

it will read the entire file twice (for each of the compute)

Is there any way to have the read result done only once?

Also are there any way to have both `compute()` to run in a sequence? (if i run it in two lines, from the dask dashboard i could see that it will run the first, clear the dasboard, and run the second one instead of running both in single sequence)

I cannot run `.compute()` for the result file because my ram can't contain it, the resulting dataframe is too big. both the checker and the output file is significantly smaller compared to the original data.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call the `dask.compute` function  on multiple Dask collections

```
a, b = dask.compute(a, b)
```

https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/api.html#dask.compute

In the future, I recommend producing an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thank you very much. Will do MCVE for next question.

Also, the dask.compute on multiple collection does share the intermediate result, which is exactly what im looking for.